# Set translation for error messages in zend2

Tags: translation, zend-framework2

I struggle to set a default language for the error messages (displayed when trying to submit a invalid form) in Zend 2. I've downloaded the code from the quick start tutorial and added the following lines to ..module\Album\config\module.config.php:

```
 //[...]
'translator' => array(
     'locale' => 'de_DE',
     'translation_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern' => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

and

```
    $translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
    $translator->setLocale('de_DE');
```

in my controller. Neither seems to work. There are some translations in ...\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\resources\languages. I don't have the Intl PHP extension installed, but I hope very much that the translation will work without this extension.

Thanks for your help,

Andreas

Comment: Can you please give the function call you use to translate in the error message?

Comment: I hope I don't have to call any functions. E.g. I want to set a form element required and expect a translated error message.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it appears that the Intl PHP Extension is really required. With the Intl Extension, you can set the default Translator to the abstract validator. From the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.messages.html%20docs):

```
$translator = new Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile(
   'phpArray',
   'resources/languages/en.php',
   'default',
   'en_US'
);
Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```